# fine tuning a mt5 model for abstractive arabic text summarization using xlsum train dataset and a validation dataset but it is not from the xlsum

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

This is my code:

```py
!pip install transformers[sentencepiece] datasets sacrebleu rouge_score py7zr -q
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric

from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer

import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

from tqdm import tqdm
import torch

nltk.download("punkt")

from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("csebuetnlp/xlsum", "arabic")
dataset

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/labeled_validation_dataset.jsonl",lines = True,orient='records')

from transformers import MT5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer, pipeline

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("tokenizer")

from transformers import MT5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer, pipeline

model_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/models/mt5-model"
model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/models/mt5-model/Copy of pytorch_model.bin"
config_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/models/mt5-model/config.json"


model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_path, config=config_path)

gen_kwargs = {"length_penalty": 0.6, "num_beams":8, "max_length": 326}

pipe = pipeline("summarization", model=model,tokenizer=tokenizer)

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_path, config=config_path).to(device)

def generate_batch_sized_chunks(list_of_elements, batch_size):
    
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_elements), batch_size):
        yield list_of_elements[i : i + batch_size]

def calculate_metric_on_test_ds(dataset, metric, model, tokenizer,
                               batch_size=16, device=device,
                               column_text="paragraph",
                               column_summary="summary"):
    
    article_batches = list(generate_batch_sized_chunks(dataset[column_text], batch_size))
    target_batches = list(generate_batch_sized_chunks(dataset[column_summary], batch_size))

    for article_batch, target_batch in tqdm(
        zip(article_batches, target_batches), total=len(article_batches)):

        inputs = tokenizer(article_batch, max_length=1024,  truncation=True,
                        padding="max_length", return_tensors="pt")

        summaries = model.generate(input_ids=inputs["input_ids"].to(device),
                         attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"].to(device),
                         length_penalty=0.8, num_beams=8, max_length=128)
        
        
        decoded_summaries = [tokenizer.decode(s, skip_special_tokens=True,
                                clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
               for s in summaries]

        decoded_summaries = [d.replace("<n>", " ") for d in decoded_summaries]


        metric.add_batch(predictions=decoded_summaries, references=target_batch)

    
    score = metric.compute()
    return score

def convert_examples_to_features___train(row):
    input_encodings = tokenizer(row['paragraph'], max_length=1024, truncation=True,padding = True)

    with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
        target_encodings = tokenizer(row['summary'], max_length=128, truncation=True,padding = True)

    return {
        'input_ids': input_encodings['input_ids'],
        'attention_mask': input_encodings['attention_mask'],
        'labels': target_encodings['input_ids']
    }

df_train_pt = df.apply(convert_examples_to_features___train, axis=1)
def convert_examples_to_features2(example_batch):
    input_encodings = tokenizer(example_batch['text'] , max_length = 520, truncation = True,padding=True )

    with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
        target_encodings = tokenizer(example_batch['summary'], max_length = 128, truncation = True ,padding = True)

    return {
        'input_ids' : input_encodings['input_ids'],
        'attention_mask': input_encodings['attention_mask'],
        'labels': target_encodings['input_ids']
    }

datasets_pt = dataset.map(convert_examples_to_features2, batched = True)


from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

seq2seq_data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=model)

trainer_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/models/mt5-val',
    num_train_epochs=150,
    warmup_steps=500,
  per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    eval_steps=500,
    save_steps=1e6,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=16,
    remove_unused_columns=False
)


seq2seq_data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=model)


trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=trainer_args,
    train_dataset=datasets_pt["train"],eval_dataset=df_train_pt,
    data_collator=seq2seq_data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
```

when i run `trainer.train()`, i always get error:

```
ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 
'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`id` in this case) have 
excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected).
```

How can I resolve this?